# Поможет ли limit_choices_to для ограничения выбора и как его сформулировать?

Tags: python, django, django-model

Часть проекта для юридической фирмы. Каждый город разбит на районы, в каждом районе свой районный суд (например, Басманный, Тверской и т.д.). В каждом суде 20-50 своих судей. Заказчику важно знать не только в каком суде находится его дело, но и у какого судьи.
Есть модель **Court** с районными судами и модель **Judges** с судьями, приписанными каждый к конкретному суду. Есть модель **Case** содержащая информацию по конкретному судебному делу, ведущемуся юристами фирмы (в данном случае я её предельно упростил). Соответственно, при заполнении поля **court** модели **Case** через админку или форму будет выскакивать список районных судов и это норм, но при заполнении поля **judge** этой модели будет выскакивать список всех судей вообще, а это сотни человек! Неудобно.
Могу ли я ограничить выбор судей в поле **judge** модели **Case** в зависимости от выбранного суда в поле **court** этой же модели?

```
class Court(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Суд')

class Judges(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Судья')
    court = models.ForeignKey('Court', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Суд')

class Case(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Процесс')
    court = models.ForeignKey('Court', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Суд')
    judge = models.ForeignKey('Judges', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Судья')
```

Можно ли как-то сформулировать **limit_choices_to** в поле **judge** модели **Case**, чтобы не вываливался весь список всех судей, а только того суда, который выбран в поле **court** модели **Case**? Или на уровне модели без JS этого сделать не получится?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы пишете что судья относиться к конкретному суду то зачем вам связь `ForeignKey`? Не лучше ли использовать `OneToOne` и тогда в `Case` определить только филд `judge`?

Comment: @5c0rp Тогда будут проблемы с логированием истории в случае, когда судья поменял место работы и перешёл в другой суд. ну или эти таблицы должны хранить только актуальную ситуацию. А дальше всё переносить в исторические.